# jquery for array of images and videos slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a jquery plugin that can accommodate both images and videos in an HTML code and show them in a slideshow. like following is my code containing data of images and videos separately (i can combine them as well)

```
 <div id="slideshow1" class="data">
        {% for item in variable_data %}
               <img src={{item}} width="800" height="600">
               <video id="MY_VIDEO_1" controls autoplay width="800" height="600" >
               <source src={{item}} type='video/mp4'>
        </video>
        {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

and I was using cycle plugin for the images already [available_here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

how can i modify or enhance this code for video functionality in slideshow?:

```
$('#slideshow1').cycle({ 
    fx:     'shuffle', 
    easing: 'easeOutBack', 
    delay:  -4000 
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you think, this is a django question?

Comment: was using django on the backend, as shown in the for loop, but I removed django